# Where do you put a global method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that is common to all my controllers:

```
func myColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 9.0/255.0, green: 134.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
}
```

Where can I put this function, so I can access it from any controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default all default access scope (`internal`) functions are available everywhere in the application. If you have this function defined in different module, you need to use `public` modifier.

To make your code clearer it is best to create extension for `UIColor`.

```
extension UIColor {
    class func myColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 9.0/255.0, green: 134.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Then you can use `myColor` same way as default `UIColor` colors.

```
let systemColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let myColor = UIColor.myColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Is your function returning the same color every time as in the question? In that case why don't you make it a static color in AppDelegate which you can access anywhere using

```
(UIApplication.sharedApplication() as AppDelegate).myColor
```

2) If your color will return a different color everytime based on your class properties but uses the same formula for all classes for e.g.

```
func myColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: (prop1 * 5)/255.0, green: prop2/255.0, blue: (prop3/2)/255.0, alpha: 1)  
}
```

you can define prop1,prop2,prop3 and the function in a base class which every class can override and set their own values for the properties. The function will not need to be overridden.

3) If the formula for calculating the color is different for every class, you can try making a protocol which defines this function and the properties. Every class which inherits from this property will have to provide their own implementation of the formula.

You can pick the appropriate solution based on your need.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add a swift file name it **UIColorExt.swift**:

```
import UIKit        
class func RGB(r: CGFloat, _ g: CGFloat, _ b: CGFloat, _ alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor{
   return UIColor(red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}
```

Usage:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.RGB(204, 119, 70)
```